# For Loop on ddply

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, plyr

I'm trying to perform a loop with for in R. What I'm trying to do I think is quite simple. I have a vector (but I'm trying also with a column in a data frame) and I have a function in dpply in which R has to substitute the values from the vector:

```
x = c(1,3,4)
```

my data frame prova1 is:

```
   anno variable value
1   1922      gen   0.5
2   1922      gen   0.0
3   1922      gen   1.5
4   1922      gen   0.0
5   1922      gen   4.0
6   1922      gen   2.5
7   1922      gen   5.0
8   1922      gen   0.0
9   1922      gen   0.0
10  1922      gen   0.0
11  1922      gen   0.0
12  1922      gen   0.0
13  1922      gen   0.0
14  1922      gen   0.0
15  1922      gen   0.0
16  1922      gen   2.5
17  1922      gen   0.0
18  1922      gen   0.0
```

also, I want r to store every result of the function in a list, thus I had created an empty list object

```
usq<-list()
```

then I use the loop

```
  n = length(x)
   for(i in n) {
  usq[[i]] <-ddply(prova1, .(anno),  summarize,
                             sum = sum(value >= x[i] ))
}
```

the problem is that R overwrite each time the whole list, thus, in the end I obtain a list with the first value `NULL` and only the last object of the list is correct.

Moreover, I would like to do the same loop on a column or a row like:

```
   gen   feb   mar   apr   mag   giu   lug   ago   set   ott   nov   dic
  3.93   5.2   3.2     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12
```

in order to get an object in the list for each column. 
Is there any way to stop R to overwrite the list? 
And how to perform the same loop on several column?

Thank you in advance,
Luca

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option with `dplyr` and `purrr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map(x, ~ prova1 %>%
            group_by(anno) %>%
            summarise(Sum = sum(value >= .x)))
```

---

In the OP's loop, 'n' is a single value i.e. `length` of 'x' = 3.  We are looping over

```
for(i in 3) # i.e. one time
```

Instead, it should be

```
for(i in 1:3)
```

i.e.

```
for(i in seq_len(n))
```

It is also better to initialize the output `list` with the predefined length

```
library(plyr)
usq <- vector('list', length(x))
for(i in seq_len(n)) {
    usq[[i]] <- ddply(prova1, .(anno),  summarize,
                         sum = sum(value >= x[i] ))
    }
```